# AngularJS - Better filtering of collection in collection with lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have a key value filter.

```
$scope.filter.subjects = [
  { Key: 27, Value: "Txt" }
  { Key: 19, Value: "Txt" }
  { Key: 7, Value: "Txt" }
  { Key: 5, Value: "Txt" }
]
```

And a result collection where I want to filter against another key value collection.

```
result = [{
  Prop1: "txt",
  Prop2: "txt",
  ...
  Subjects: [{
    { Key: 7, Value: "Txt" }
    { Key: 5, Value: "Txt" }
  ],
  ...
}]
```

This lodash filtering is currently working but it looks very inefficient and clunky. I can change the filter and result model on the backend to instead of a collection of key and value I can return an object with the values mapped like this:

```
...
Subjects: {
  7: "Txt",
  5: "txt"
}
...
```

and change the filter to:

```
$scope.filter.subjects = {
  27: "Txt",
  19: "Txt",
  7: "Txt",
  5: "Txt"
}
```

If this can make it more efficient

Here is the current filter:

```
...
var filteredList = angular.copy($scope.data);
...
if ($scope.filter.Subject.length > 0) {         
    filteredList = _.filter(filteredList, function (o) {
        return _.find(o.Subjects, function (y) {
            return _.find($scope.filter.Subject, ["Key", y.Key]);
        });
    });
}
...
$scope.result = filteredList;
```

Comment: can you show us what is an exact output expected against an exact input? It seems you just want to filter out some result from results, and no further tuning inside.

Comment: Yes, I have other simpler filter in the same method which just filters against a single property with the $filter method from angular. So it's building up a filtered collection where the results include in any of the filters added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not sure what you are exactly trying. If your `$scope.filter.Subject` is just an map object like `{27: 'Txt', 12: '...'}` instead of a `[{key: '', value: ''}, {<key,value>}, ...}]` then you can easily skip the inner most iteration for find in the context of exactly what you are trying in the given example, and can change the code to:

```
filteredList = _.filter(filteredList, function (o) {
    return _.find(o.Subjects, function (y) {
        return $scope.filter.subjects[y.Key];
    });
});
```